# In REPL for node.js on terminal, i have to use require('./index.js') instead of just typing node index.js. I am trying to use the latter. Suggestions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

```
node index.js
node index.js
     ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

> index.js
ReferenceError: index is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:334:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:531:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:238:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:582:8)
> node index.js
node index.js
     ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

> node ('./index.js')
ReferenceError: node is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:23:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:334:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:531:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:238:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:582:8)
> node require ('./index.js')
node require ('./index.js')
     ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

> require('./index.js')
hey
{}
>
```

While on stack I notice require() being a popular choice but havent seen any hint of anyone explaining why this may be. Maybe it just happens to be this is how I must do it. Ive run this a couple times in different ways to be sure there were no other alternatives readily available to someone of my beginner level in node. I don't believe it has anything to do with my path but then again I could be wrong. Im more interested in just making things quicker for myself. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: You're in the node terminal, `node <file>` is run in the regular terminal...

Comment: Well... REPL is a JavaScript console, it's normal that you cannot run arbitrary shell commands.

Comment: yeah i know this, ive run it through that way before. im just curious on a video i saw on how someone ran it differently through the way ive explaned.

Comment: Type `.help` to see the available commands. Perhaps you mean `.load` :-?

Comment: yeah .load works. thanks @alvaro, ive been going through the node.js doc today i noticed these commands while going through the REPL section. i will definitely take a better look at them after this

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have a blinking cursor to type and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key executes stuff immediately it doesn't mean you're in an operating system shell. Node's REPL console runs a **JavaScript** interpreter so you're expected to type JavaScript code, not arbitrary system commands.

It has, though, some specific [internal commands and special keys](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/repl.html#repl_commands_and_special_keys) that are identified by a leading dot (so they can't be confused with regular code). You can see a list with the `.help` command:

```
> .help
.break    Sometimes you get stuck, this gets you out
.clear    Alias for .break
.editor   Enter editor mode
.exit     Exit the repl
.help     Print this help message
.load     Load JS from a file into the REPL session
.save     Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file
```

You probably had `.load` in mind.